# Creating dynamic paragraphs for strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, substring

I've the following problem with creating dynamic `<p>` elements using a response! The response is plain text. I need to identify if the string contains line breaks or paragraph separations.

**example string**

```
All rates are inclusive of the applicable Service charge, VAT, NBT & TDL currently at the prevailing 10%, 12%, 2% & 1% respectively. In the event of a change in the Service charge, VAT, NBT & TDL or the introduction of additional taxes, the Contract Rates will be adjusted accordingly.

 All rates are inclusive of the applicable Service charge, VAT, NBT & TDL currently at the prevailing 10%, 12%, 2% & 1% respectively. In the event of a change in the Service charge, VAT, NBT & TDL or the introduction of additional taxes, the Contract Rates will be adjusted accordingly.

 All rates are inclusive of the applicable Service charge, VAT, NBT & TDL currently at the prevailing 10%, 12%, 2% & 1% respectively. In the event of a change in the Service charge, VAT, NBT & TDL or the introduction of additional taxes, the Contract Rates will be adjusted accordingly.
```

This string is three paragraphs combined together! how can I identify each separate paragraph to create seperate `<p>` tags for each paragraphs using javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You should really post some code, but try this

```
var paragraphed = "<p>" + originalString.split("\n").join("</p><p>") + "</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  var responsestr="<your response text here>";  /*assuming that variable responsestr holds the response*/
  var str=encodeURIComponent(responsestr);
  var pArray=str.split("%0D%0A");
  var result=[];
  for(var i=0;i<pArray.length;i++){
    result.push("<p>"+decodeURIComponent(pArray[i])+"</p>\r\n");
  }
  var finalstr=result.join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
var s = "your string";
var paragraphs = s.split("\n")
      .filter(function (item) { return item !== ""; })
      .map(function (item) { return "<p>" + item + "</p>"; });
```